# Efficient comparison of POSIXct in data.table

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, posixct, subset

Hello I am looking for an efficient way of selecting `POSIXct` rows from a `data.table` such that the time of day is less than say `12:00:00` (NOTE that millisecond is NOT required, so we can use `ITime` for example)

```
set.seed(1); N = 1e7;
DT = data.table(dts = .POSIXct(1e5*rnorm(N), tz="GMT"))
DT
                               dts
#       1: 1969-12-31 06:35:54.618925
#       2: 1970-01-01 05:06:04.332422
#     ---                           
# 9999999: 1970-01-03 00:37:00.035565
#10000000: 1969-12-30 08:30:23.624506
```

One solution (the problem here is that the cast could be costly if N is big)

```
f <- function(t, st, et) {time <- as.ITime(t); return(time>=as.ITime(st) & time<=as.ITime(et))}
P <- function(t, s) { #geekTrader solution
    ep <- .parseISO8601(s) 
    if(grepl('T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}', s)){
        first.time <- as.double(ep$first.time)
        last.time <- as.double(ep$last.time)-31449600
        SecOfDay <- as.double(t) %% 86400
        return(SecOfDay >= first.time & SecOfDay <= last.time )
    } else {
        return(t >= ep$first.time & t <= ep$last.time)    
    }
}
```

Quick look about the perf

```
system.time(resf <- DT[f(dts,'00:00:00','11:59:59')])
   user  system elapsed 
   1.01    0.28    1.29
system.time(resP <- DT[P(dts,'T00:00:00/T11:59:59')])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.64    0.13    0.76 

identical(resf,resP)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Are you happy enough to create an `itime` column and key by it?

Comment: @mnel: yes so we do a binary search...

Comment: You really shouldn't edit people's answers into your question

Comment: I see... why is that ? looks better for understanding to me...

Comment: @statquant : just curious why was bounty awarded to the Richie's answer?

Comment: @geektrader : I am curious too I think it is supposed to be 50/50 as both of you got >4 up, that's why I did not award it myself. I've let the admin know. Sorry about that.

Comment: @statquant : ok. I was quite surprised when I saw bounty being awarded to `as.POSIXlt` answer :)

Comment: @geektrader: It seems that ONLY the oldest answer with a more than 2 points gets the bounty! I did not know the rule, as the whole bounty is always taken off the OP I thought the whole would be awawred or at least granted pro-rata... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 P <- function(t, s) {
  ep <- .parseISO8601(s)

  if(grepl('T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}', s)){
    first.time <- as.double(ep$first.time)
    last.time <- as.double(ep$last.time)-31449600
    SecOfDay <- as.double(t) %% 86400
    return(SecOfDay >= first.time & SecOfDay <= last.time )

  } else {
    return(t >= ep$first.time & t <= ep$last.time)    
  }

}

F <- function(t, st, et) {
  time <- as.ITime(t) 
  return(time>=as.ITime(st) & time<=as.ITime(et))
}


 Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
 N = 1e7;
 set.seed(1);

 DT <- data.table(dts = .POSIXct(1e5*rnorm(N), tz="GMT"))


 system.time(resP <- DT[P(dts, 'T00:00:00/T12:00:00'), ])
##   user  system elapsed 
##   1.11    0.11    1.22 
 system.time(resF <- DT[F(dts,'00:00:00','12:00:00')])
##   user  system elapsed 
##   2.22    0.29    2.51 

 resP
##                         dts
##      1: 1969-12-31 06:35:54
##      2: 1970-01-01 05:06:04
##      3: 1969-12-31 00:47:17
##      4: 1970-01-01 09:09:10
##      5: 1969-12-31 01:12:33
##     ---                    
##5000672: 1970-01-01 06:08:15
##5000673: 1970-01-01 05:02:27
##5000674: 1969-12-31 02:25:24
##5000675: 1970-01-03 00:37:00
##5000676: 1969-12-30 08:30:23
 resF
##                         dts
##      1: 1969-12-31 06:35:54
##      2: 1970-01-01 05:06:04
##      3: 1969-12-31 00:47:17
##      4: 1970-01-01 09:09:10
##      5: 1969-12-31 01:12:33
##     ---                    
##5000672: 1970-01-01 06:08:15
##5000673: 1970-01-01 05:02:27
##5000674: 1969-12-31 02:25:24
##5000675: 1970-01-03 00:37:00
##5000676: 1969-12-30 08:30:23

 #Check the correctness
 resP[,list(mindts=max(dts)),by=list(as.Date(dts))]
##       as.Date              mindts
## 1: 1969-12-31 1969-12-31 12:00:00
## 2: 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 12:00:00
## 3: 1969-12-29 1969-12-29 12:00:00
## 4: 1970-01-02 1970-01-02 12:00:00
## 5: 1969-12-30 1969-12-30 12:00:00
## 6: 1970-01-03 1970-01-03 12:00:00
## 7: 1970-01-04 1970-01-04 11:59:59
## 8: 1970-01-05 1970-01-05 11:59:45
## 9: 1969-12-28 1969-12-28 12:00:00
##10: 1969-12-27 1969-12-27 11:59:21
##11: 1970-01-06 1970-01-06 10:53:21
##12: 1969-12-26 1969-12-26 10:15:03
##13: 1970-01-07 1970-01-07 08:21:55
 resF[,list(mindts=max(dts)),by=list(as.Date(dts))]
##       as.Date              mindts
## 1: 1969-12-31 1969-12-31 12:00:00
## 2: 1970-01-01 1970-01-01 12:00:00
## 3: 1969-12-29 1969-12-29 12:00:00
## 4: 1970-01-02 1970-01-02 12:00:00
## 5: 1969-12-30 1969-12-30 12:00:00
## 6: 1970-01-03 1970-01-03 12:00:00
## 7: 1970-01-04 1970-01-04 11:59:59
## 8: 1970-01-05 1970-01-05 11:59:45
## 9: 1969-12-28 1969-12-28 12:00:00
##10: 1969-12-27 1969-12-27 11:59:21
##11: 1970-01-06 1970-01-06 10:53:21
##12: 1969-12-26 1969-12-26 10:15:03
##13: 1970-01-07 1970-01-07 08:21:55
```

Now some demo of nice `xts` style subsetting

```
 DT[P(dts, '1970')]
##                         dts
##      1: 1970-01-01 05:06:04
##      2: 1970-01-02 20:18:48
##      3: 1970-01-01 09:09:10
##      4: 1970-01-01 13:32:22
##      5: 1970-01-01 20:30:32
##     ---                    
##5001741: 1970-01-02 15:51:12
##5001742: 1970-01-03 01:41:31
##5001743: 1970-01-01 06:08:15
##5001744: 1970-01-01 05:02:27
##5001745: 1970-01-03 00:37:00
 DT[P(dts, '197001')]
##                         dts
##      1: 1970-01-01 05:06:04
##      2: 1970-01-02 20:18:48
##      3: 1970-01-01 09:09:10
##      4: 1970-01-01 13:32:22
##      5: 1970-01-01 20:30:32
##     ---                    
##5001741: 1970-01-02 15:51:12
##5001742: 1970-01-03 01:41:31
##5001743: 1970-01-01 06:08:15
##5001744: 1970-01-01 05:02:27
##5001745: 1970-01-03 00:37:00
 DT[P(dts, '19700102')]
##                         dts
##      1: 1970-01-02 20:18:48
##      2: 1970-01-02 17:59:38
##      3: 1970-01-02 07:14:53
##      4: 1970-01-02 02:13:03
##      5: 1970-01-02 01:31:37
##     ---                    
##1519426: 1970-01-02 11:25:24
##1519427: 1970-01-02 10:00:21
##1519428: 1970-01-02 05:21:25
##1519429: 1970-01-02 05:11:26
##1519430: 1970-01-02 15:51:12
 DT[P(dts, '19700102 00:00:00/19700103 12:00:00')]
##                         dts
##      1: 1970-01-02 20:18:48
##      2: 1970-01-02 17:59:38
##      3: 1970-01-02 07:14:53
##      4: 1970-01-02 02:13:03
##      5: 1970-01-02 01:31:37
##     ---                    
##1785762: 1970-01-02 05:21:25
##1785763: 1970-01-02 05:11:26
##1785764: 1970-01-02 15:51:12
##1785765: 1970-01-03 01:41:31
##1785766: 1970-01-03 00:37:00

 #Check the correctness again
 DT[P(dts, '19700102 00:00:00/19700103 12:00:00'), max(dts)]
##[1] "1970-01-03 12:00:00 GMT"
 DT[P(dts, '19700102 00:00:00/19700103 12:00:00'), min(dts)]
##[1] "1970-01-02 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, I tend to use HHMMSS stored as plain integer; i.e. no epoch, no class.

Comment: Nice. Storing time as seconds and `%% 86400` seems like a nice straightforward solution, and mostly likely pretty fast.

Comment: @statquant Seem to be working ok after we replace `as.integer` by `as.double`

Comment: Well done, identical. But would that work on a leap year ? cause there is more than 86400 seconds those years...

Comment: It will work on leap year too. POSIXct ignores leap seconds. Read that somewhere in documentation

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way of doing this is to convert to `POSIXlt` and extract the hour component.

```
hour(as.POSIXlt(DT$dts, "GMT")) < 12
```

This seems to be comparable in performance to the other techniques discussed (and is easier to understand).

Comment: +1 Surely this is just about the fastest way? If not, it is certainly the most comprehensible to me. It reduced 1e7 rows to ~ 5e6 rows (what I would expect given `rnorm`) in ~ 1 second. And requires no more than base R.

Comment: `data.table::hour` is already using `as.POSIXlt`, so you can write something like `DT[, morning:= (hour(DT$dts) < 12)]`.

Comment: Have you guys tried benchmarking? My initial benchmarking revealed `as.POSIXlt` didn't really give as much performance boost..

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that uses some of the functionality from **[xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts)** to accomplish what you want.  This is not a great solution because `xts` objects must be ordered by time, but `data.table` objects do not have to be.  Also, it may not be terribly fast since there is some redundant work being done by `xts` and `data.table`.  Nonetheless, I thought it might be interesting.

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)
set.seed(1); N = 1e5;
# I tweaked the following line to make this reproducible in other timezones.
DT = data.table(dts = .POSIXct(1e5*rnorm(N), tz="GMT"))
setkey(DT, dts)  # must sort on time first so that the `xts` object we're about 
                 # to create has the same order
DT[, XTS:=xts(rep(NA, .N), dts)]  # add a dummy xts object as a column
DT[XTS["T00:00:00/T11:59:59.999999", which=TRUE]][, list(dts)] 
                       dts
    1: 1969-12-27 00:28:41
    2: 1969-12-27 00:34:00
    3: 1969-12-27 03:11:21
    4: 1969-12-27 04:20:27
    5: 1969-12-28 00:00:21
   ---                    
49825: 1970-01-05 08:05:22
49826: 1970-01-05 09:35:32
49827: 1970-01-05 09:49:49
49828: 1970-01-05 09:50:27
49829: 1970-01-05 11:07:32
```

The above uses an `xts`-style subsetting string to get the rows where the time is between 00:00:00 and 12:00:00 for every day.  Using `which=TRUE` returns the row number instead of the data from that row, so that we can subset the `data.table` by those rows.

You could use a string like "1970-01-01" to get all data from that day, or "1970-01" to get all data from January 1970, or "1970-01-01/1970-01-02" to get all rows from those two days.

Comment: Yes, as you point out, the ordering (`setkey` operation) seems to be expensive on bigger tables (1e7). And for some reason, the test result with 1e7 rows (seed = 1) gives about 60 rows more in your solution (maybe it's got to do with the milliseconds?)

Comment: @Arun "T00:00:00/T12:00:00" will also include times up to but not including 12:00:01.  I have edited to use a more precise subset string that gives the same number of rows as the OP.

Comment: Thanks Gsee, though I find this x2 time less efficient than based method (function `f`), and that's without the sorting

Answer (score 0):

A late entry, but I think that the `as.POSIXlt` solution will create a named list of vectors, of which you only want the hour

I would key by an `ITime` column and then use a binary search to subset those times before 12pm

There are `60*60 *12 - 1` seconds before 12pm so `seq_len(43199)` will return everything up to (but not including) 12pm

```
# create IDate and ITime columns and key by time
setkey(DT[, c('Date','Time') := IDateTime(dts)],Time)

# subset times before 12pm
DT[.(seq_len(43199))]
```

Comment: That's very good actually, let me test the leap years and summer time stuff, it is always more tricky than it seems. Thanks